# How to extend cypress.json config to other configuration files?

Tags: cypress, cypress-configuration

In my Cypress 10 project, I have the following config files:

- `cypress/cypress.config.js`
- `cypress/config/qa.json` (Points at my QA environment).
- `cypress/config/staging.json` (Points at my Staging environment).

Everything in the below `cypress.config.js` file is common across both QA & Staging environments:

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const fs = require('fs-extra')
const readDirRecursive = require('fs-readdir-recursive')
const createBundler = require("@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor")
const preprocessor = require("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor")
const createEsbuildPlugin = require("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/esbuild")
const stdLibBrowser = require('node-stdlib-browser')
const plugin = require('node-stdlib-browser/helpers/esbuild/plugin')
const mysql = require('mysql')

function queryTestDb(query, config) {
    // creates a new mysql connection using credentials from cypress.json env's
    const connection = mysql.createConnection(config.env.db)
        // start connection to db
    connection.connect()
        // exec query + disconnect to db as a Promise
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.query(query, (error, results) => {
            if (error) reject(error)
            else {
                connection.end()
                return resolve(results)
            }
        })
    })
}

async function setupNodeEvents(on, config) {

    await preprocessor.addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config, {
        omitBeforeRunHandler: true
    })

    on('before:run', () => {
        fs.emptyDirSync('./test-results')
        preprocessor.beforeRunHandler(config)
    })

    on(
        'file:preprocessor',
        createBundler({
            inject: [require.resolve('node-stdlib-browser/helpers/esbuild/shim')],
            define: {
                global: 'global',
                process: 'process',
                Buffer: 'Buffer'
            },
            plugins: [plugin(stdLibBrowser), createEsbuildPlugin.default(config)],
        })
    )

    on('task', {
        readFolder(path) {
            return readDirRecursive(path)
        }
    })

    on('task', {
        queryDb: query => {
            return queryTestDb(query, config)
        }
    })

    return config
}

module.exports = defineConfig({
    defaultCommandTimeout: 30000,
    requestTimeout: 30000,
    responseTimeout: 60000,
    pageLoadTimeout: 90000,
    numTestsKeptInMemory: 1,
    chromeWebSecurity: false,
    experimentalWebKitSupport: false,
    screenshotsFolder: 'test-results/screenshots',
    videosFolder: 'test-results/videos',
    viewportWidth: 1920,
    viewportHeight: 1200,
    watchForFileChanges: false,
    screenshotOnRunFailure: true,
    video: false,
    videoCompression: 8,
    reporter: 'spec',
    reporterOptions: {
        mochaFile: 'test-results/tests-output/result-[hash].xml',
        toConsole: true
    },
    retries: {
        runMode: 1,
        openMode: 0
    },
    e2e: {
        setupNodeEvents,
        specPattern: 'cypress/tests/**/*.feature',
    },
})
```

Even though a lot of the values will remain the same for QA & Staging, I need to use different config files for them.

Specifically, the `e2e.baseUrl` & `env.db` values will be different in these environments. Every other value will be the same in QA & Staging.

Here is what I have tried to do in my `qa.json` file:

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

const baseConfig = require('../../cypress.config.js')

const fs = require('fs-extra')
const readDirRecursive = require('fs-readdir-recursive')
const createBundler = require("@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor")
const preprocessor = require("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor")
const createEsbuildPlugin = require("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/esbuild")
const stdLibBrowser = require('node-stdlib-browser')
const plugin = require('node-stdlib-browser/helpers/esbuild/plugin')
const mysql = require('mysql')

const baseUrl = 'https://qa.com'

const env = {
    db: {
        host: 'myHost',
        user: 'myUser',
        password: 'myPassowrd',
        database: 'myDb',
    }
}

function queryTestDb(query, config) {
    // creates a new mysql connection using credentials from cypress.json env's
    const connection = mysql.createConnection(config.env.db)
        // start connection to db
    connection.connect()
        // exec query + disconnect to db as a Promise
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.query(query, (error, results) => {
            if (error) reject(error)
            else {
                connection.end()
                return resolve(results)
            }
        })
    })
}

async function setupNodeEvents(on, config) {

    await preprocessor.addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config, {
        omitBeforeRunHandler: true
    })

    on('before:run', () => {
        fs.emptyDirSync('./test-results')
        preprocessor.beforeRunHandler(config)
    })

    on(
        'file:preprocessor',
        createBundler({
            inject: [require.resolve('node-stdlib-browser/helpers/esbuild/shim')],
            define: {
                global: 'global',
                process: 'process',
                Buffer: 'Buffer'
            },
            plugins: [plugin(stdLibBrowser), createEsbuildPlugin.default(config)],
        })
    )

    on('task', {
        readFolder(path) {
            return readDirRecursive(path)
        }
    })

    on('task', {
        queryDb: query => {
            return queryTestDb(query, config)
        }
    })

    return config
}

module.exports = defineConfig({
    defaultCommandTimeout: 30000,
    requestTimeout: 30000,
    responseTimeout: 60000,
    pageLoadTimeout: 90000,
    numTestsKeptInMemory: 1,
    chromeWebSecurity: false,
    experimentalWebKitSupport: false,
    screenshotsFolder: 'test-results/screenshots',
    videosFolder: 'test-results/videos',
    viewportWidth: 1920,
    viewportHeight: 1200,
    watchForFileChanges: false,
    screenshotOnRunFailure: true,
    video: false,
    videoCompression: 8,
    reporter: 'spec',
    reporterOptions: {
        mochaFile: 'test-results/tests-output/result-[hash].xml',
        toConsole: true
    },
    retries: {
        runMode: 1,
        openMode: 0
    },
    e2e: {
        setupNodeEvents,
        baseUrl: baseUrl,
        specPattern: 'cypress/tests/**/*.feature',
    },
    env: {
        ...baseConfig,     // values from imported file
        ...env,            // add or overwrite with values from above
        
    }
})
```

As you can see, I've managed to move my `baseUrl` & `env` values into `qa.json`.

However, there are still a lot of duplicate values in `cypress.config.js` & `qa.json`.

The command I am using to run the tests is `npx cypress open --config-file cypress/config/aqua.js`

How can I re-use the `queryTestDb()` function `setupNodeEvents()` function & the other config values in `cypress.config.js`?

Comment: Do you have a reason to think Cypress supports that? It's not a feature of JSON itself.

Answer (score 3):

There's a package that does pretty much what you want to do.

[cypress-extends](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-extends)

> Cypress plugin that adds "extends" support to the configuration file. This allows the config files to remain DRY and avoid duplicating data, but still have multiple files for different scenarios.

```js
// cypress.json
{
  "extends": "./base.json"
}
// base.json
{
  "fixturesFolder": false,
  "supportFile": false,
  "$schema": "https://on.cypress.io/cypress.schema.json"
}
```

In the docs [Extending the Cypress Config File](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/06/18/extending-the-cypress-config-file/)

---

#### Cypress v10

With the latest Cypress version, config changes from `.json` to `.js` file.

Now you can just import and merge the base.json, but you need to be careful about sub-sections of the comfig

**cypress.config.js**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')
const baseConfig = require('base.json')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: baseConfig.baseUrl || 'http://localhost:1234'  // example OR 
  }
})
```

Or maybe this is more general

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')
const baseConfig = require('base.json')

const e2e = {
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:1234',
  fixturesFolder: false,
  supportFile: false,
  "$schema": "https://on.cypress.io/cypress.schema.json"
}

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    ...e2e,           // values from above
    ...baseConfig     // add or overwrite from imported file
  }
})
```

It's more powerful merging in javascript, but also easier to get wrong. Please refer to the [Testing Type-Specific Options](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Testing-Type-Specific-Options) for a reference to what goes where in the new format.

Comment: Is there any update on how to do this with Cypress 10 config file `cypress.config.js`?

Comment: cypress-extends hasn't been updated, but in Cypress 10 it's probably no longer necessary. Will add v10 code.

Comment: Which approach would be best if I had seperate configurations say for example, a `QA.json` & a `UAT.json`? And I'd want to be able to specify which configuration to use when running the tests

Comment: It sounds like you want to to do this [Specifying an Alternative Config File](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Specifying-an-Alternative-Config-File), in which case you don't need `extends` at all.

Comment: The reason I was trying to extend is because there are some common config values in the environments, & wanted to avoid the duplication.

Comment: Yes of course, I forgot the original question there. You can still use the version 9 syntax you have in the question, but the extensions are different. `npx cypress run --config-file staging.config.js`. Each file is as shown above. You may want to change the order of `...e2e` and `...baseConfig` depending on which one takes priority.

Comment: OK, I think I am getting there. if I run `npx cypress run --config-file staging.config.js`, what in your `cypress.config.js` is related to my `staging.config.js`? Where is the `base.json` file?

Comment: The whole file is `staging.config.js` if you specify it thus: `npx cypress run --config-file staging.config.js`. `base.json` is the data common to staging and qa, etc

Comment: Ah yes, gotcha! I was thinking the above file was the "common" file. That makes sense, I'll try this when I'm at my desk & will accept it then too, appreciate the help!

Comment: Hi @Fody, I've updated my question with my latest attempt. I'm unsure how to use the `common` values from the `cypress.config.js` now when using `staging.config.js`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use lodash (looks like it's a dependency of cypress anyway), this worked for me in cypress 13

##### cypress.custom.js

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const baseConfig = require("./cypress.config.js");
const { merge } = require("lodash");

module.exports = defineConfig(merge(baseConfig, {
    e2e: {
        baseUrl: "http://different-base-url",
        ...any other overrides
    },
}));
```

Then run `npx cypress open --config-file ./cypress.custom.js`

I wasn't sure what `defineConfig` was returning in my base `cypress.config.js` but it looks like you can use it as a normal object.

I used lodash's merge instead of `Object.assign` or spread because I wanted to deep merge the config.

Answer (score -1):

While Fody's answer is really good - and led me in the right direction. Then I couldn't get it to work completely.

It also shows how to import a `.json`-file as baseConfig, where I wanted to have a `.js`-file, so I could have comments and more possibilities.

I solved this like this:

**defaultConfig.js**

```js
module.exports = {

  paths: {
    cartPathName: 'cart',
    shopPathName: 'shop',
  },

  files: {
    tmpFolder: '/tmp',
    secretFolder: '/secret',
  },

  timeouts: {
    tinyTimeout: 3000,
    shortTimeout: 10000,
    mediumTimeout: 20000,
    longTimeout: 30000,
    hugeTimeout: 60000,
  },

  specPattern: [
    'cypress/e2e/some-custom-folder/some-test.cy.js',
    'cypress/e2e/**/*.js',
    'cypress/e2e/*.js',
  ],

  viewportWidth: 1250,
  viewportHeight: 1000
};
```

**cypress.config.js**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress');
const defaultConfig = require('./defaultConfig');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      return require('./cypress/plugins/index.js')(on, config);
    },
    video: false,
    specPattern: [
      ...defaultConfigs.specPattern
    ],
    ...defaultConfigs.viewportWidth,
    ...defaultConfigs.viewportHeight
  },
  env: {

    // Timeouts
    ...defaultConfigs.timeouts,

    // Files
    ...defaultConfigs.files,

    // URLs and paths
    ...defaultConfigs.paths,

    // Meta
    name: 'development',
    currentDomain: 'example.com',
  }
});
```